# I have to update my RecyclerView adapter for every x seconds

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, postdelayed

I am fetching data from database and showing it into `RecyclerView`.But I have to update the `RecyclerView` every `x milliseconds/seconds`.

Here is my code. Please help.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_download, container, false);

    rvLatestTrack = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    linearLayoutEmpty = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutEmpty);

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    rvLatestTrack.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    getData();
    return view;
}
public void getData() {
    Database database = new Database(getContext());
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = database.getWritableDatabase();
    String SELECT_DATA_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + DB_Const.TABLE_NAME_SONGS;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SELECT_DATA_QUERY, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            DownloadsModel downloadsModel;
            do {
                String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Const.SONG_TITLE));
                String Download_percentage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Const.Completed_percentage));
                String SongURL = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_Const.URL));
                downloadsModel = new DownloadsModel(fileName, Download_percentage, SongURL);
                arrayList.add(downloadsModel);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            rvLatestTrack.setAdapter(new DownloadsAdaptor(getContext(), arrayList));
        }
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        linearLayoutEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In adapter constructor, add a timer to schedule task

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getData();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
new Timer().schedule(task, 0, 3000);
```

Comment: It's not Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the in-built [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

for this:

- lets you do expensive work on a background thread without causing UI stutter
- has a `onProgressUpdate`callback precisely for updating the UI

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare your `DownloadsAdapter` global:

```
DownloadsAdapter adapter = new DownloadsAdaptor(getContext(), arrayList)
```

and then

```
private void update() {
  Handler handler = new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        arrayList = ...
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //or notifyItemInserted or notifyItemRemoved as per your need.
        update(); // recursive call
     }
  }, 1000);
}
```

This will update your list every 1000 microseconds (x time) and notify the `RecyclerView` adapter of a change in the data.

Comment: this just do once

Comment: Didn't get you?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Of course. The UI will be unresponsive if you set x to 1000ms (1 second, too low). Try updating your recycler after a greater time than 1 second

Comment: Yes, you can do that, just set a higher time for updating the recyclerView (like 10000ms or so)

Comment: You mean 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes. It is recommended that you don't follow this approach altogether. Rather you should look for change in the Database and then update recyclerView

Comment: Please explain that approach...
How can i look for database for update ?

Comment: Database updating in very fast session

Comment: Create an interface and place it in your database's insert method and use this callback in this fragment of yours. After every callback, just update

Comment: Ok I will try that